# How to get all Preferences stored in Xamarin Preferences?

Tags: c#, xamarin, preferences

I am using Xamarin forms Preferences to store values.  I want to be able to get all of my preferences so i can find a certain few and read their values.  All the documentation only shows being able to Get a specific preference if i know the name.  Mine are created dynamically, so I dont know the names at runtime.

This is the documentation i am referencing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.preferences?view=xamarin-essentials

Any ideas?

Comment: preferences are stored in a json file, so you can just open it and read it directly.  See the Essentials source on github to get the file path